# How to get the full file path from fileupload using jquery

Tags: jquery, c#-2.0

I have got on fileupload control as below in my html.

```
<input type="file" id="fuExcel" name="fuExcel">
```

Now I want to read full file path from above fileupload using jquery, for example if I select any file from location **(d:\test\myexcel.xslx)**, I am getting **myexcel.xslx** only from below jquery code.

```
var excelfilepath = $('input[type=file]').val();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible because is a security feature in modern browsers.

For example: if you try the code you got on IE8 you will get all path.

but if you do it in chrome or other you will get just the name of the file or a kind of "C:\fakepath\"

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't. It's a browser security issue that they really don't want you working around.  There is no standards based solution that will do this in modern browsers.

Comment: Any other way to achieve above thing